# Sorting worksheets in a workbook user defined

Tags: excel, vba

i have a question and i am new to VB. Please help me!

I have a workbook with different worksheets and i want to sort them according to the range of order that i give in "Csheet". This is the code below and it works fine. But i wanted to implement this on a different workbook. And it does not work. Can you help me with this please!!!!

```
Dim SortOrder As Variant
Dim Ndx As Long
With Worksheets("CSheet").Range("A1:A3")
    For Ndx = .Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        Worksheets(.Cells(Ndx).Value).Move before:=Worksheets(1)
    Next Ndx
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Change `Worksheets(.Cells(Ndx).Value).Move before:=Worksheets(1)` to `Workbooks("BlahBlah").Worksheets(.Cells(Ndx).Value).Move before:=Workbooks("BlahBlah").Worksheets(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Based on my comments, here is a more stuctured way to do it. I just quickly typed it and hence it is not tested. Let me know if you face any error.

The reason why your code will not work for the other workbook is because you are not specifying in which workbook you want the sheets to sort. You need to fully qualify your objects.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim thisWb As Workbook, thatWb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i  As Long

    Set thisWb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = thisWb.Sheets("CSheet")

    Set thatWb = Workbooks("BlahBlah")

    For i = 3 To 1 Step -1
        With ws
            thatWb.Worksheets(.Cells(i, 1).Value).Move _
            before:=thatWb.Worksheets(1)
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello@Siddarth, Thank you so much for the reply. I used the same code as yours. But did not help. I am new to VB. so learning step by step. Please bare with me. I created a workbook called "ThisWorkBook" and a worksheet" Csheet" with the worksheets name from a1 to a3 (namely a,c,b). and created a macro in that sheet and pasted your code. Created one more Workbook "BlahBlah" with worksheets a,b,c. I run the macro from this worksheet having opened that "thisworkbook" sheet at the back. Run the macro using ALT+F* for "blahblah" sheet. It says subcript out of range. can you please help mewiththis.

Comment: @suki I added an `.xls` on the worksheet name to fix the error.  Try: `Set thatWb = Workbooks("BlahBlah.xls")`

Comment: Hello @portland runner, I still get the same error,

Comment: I should have mentioned that the file extension needs to be the same as what workbook `BlahBlah` is saved as.  It might be `.xlsx` or `.xlsm`

Comment: Hello ! Sorry again. this was an example. i tried doing it for a bigger example with more tabs and it popped as "Object Required". i am not able to attach the examples for you here. can you help me with that? Thanks

Comment: Hello @PortlandRunner , i have an issue, i have mentioned in CSheet the tabs order for instance a,b,d,c,e and in the "blahblah" i have only a,b,d , it gives a subscript out of range error. Is ther a possibility to still sort it even if it misses some. Please help!!!

Comment: Try adding `On Error Resume Next` just after the `With ws` line